# How to Search / Grep a specific word in a file?

Tags: shell, search, grep

Examples:

```
$ grep -w "edición" /tmp/apn_
edición acción__n
post-edición acción__n

$ grep -w "bar" /tmp/apn_
bar abril__n
barítono abismo__n
barógrafo abismo__n
barómetro abismo__n
barón barón__n
```

I only want that "bar" or "edición", not other results where these are sub-strings. The purpose of -w flag isn't being fulfilled here. Please suggest me what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this happens because your locale variable isn't set correctly.

```
% LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep -w bar as
bar abril__n

% LANG=bla grep -w bar as
bar abril__n
barítono abismo__n
barógrafo abismo__n
barómetro abismo__n
barón barón__n
```

Comment: $ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep -w "bar" /tmp/apn_
almíbar abril__n
bar abril__n
barítono abismo__n
barógrafo abismo__n
barómetro abismo__n
barón barón__n

Comment: @user2238884 Do you have it in your locale.conf / locale.gen? Did you run `locale-gen` or whatever?

Comment: no i didn't run any locale-gen, i ran on the terminal as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Form the `grep` manpage:

> The test is that the matching substring must either be at the
>   beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a
>   non-word  constituent  character. Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

It appears that grep treats `í` and the like as 'non-word' letters, hence they fool -w.

A possible workaround would be to write your own regular expression such as this one:

```
grep -P "(^|[[:space:]]+|[[:punct:]]+)bar([[:space:]]+|[[:punct:]]+|$)"
```

You might have to look at a few corner cases based on your input text, but this is the general idea.

The cleaner way would still be to make grep understand your locale though.